# How do you add a character to a variable without a space in Java?

Tags: java

I have this program that displays the cost per gallon of gasoline.

```
System.out.printf("%10s %.2f %s %n", "At", cost , "per gallon,");
```

The output displays

> At 5.12 per gallon,

but I want it to display

> At $5.12 per gallon,

I have tried to add the $ right after "At" but it displays a space before showing the cost. Is there a way to remove the space between "$

Comment: The space is in your format string.

Comment: Can't you just put the `$` in your format string?

Comment: `System.out.printf("%10s $%.2f %s %n", "At", cost, "per gallon,");`

Comment: And the rest of the constants could go to the format string as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily without using a lot of variables like this :

```
System.out.printf("At $%.2f per gallon,", cost);
```

If you still want variables , then try this :

```
System.out.printf("%10s $%.2f %s %n", "At", cost , "per gallon,");
```

Comment: Thank you, I just started to learn Java and didn't know that spaces in format specifications affected the output.

Answer (score 5):

An easier way would just be

```
System.out.printf("At $%.2f per gallon,%n", cost);
```

No need for all those `%s`s and string literals, just put the strings in directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%10s $%.2f %s %n", "At", cost , "per gallon,");
```